# Does a symmetric matrix $A^2$ imply a symmetric $A$?

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples

Does a symmetric matrix $A^2$  imply a symmetric $A$?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which is symmetric.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

No, for instance take $A$ antisymmetric.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** No, for instance some nilpotent matrices.