# If some power $A^n$ of a matrix $A$ is symmetric, is $A$ necessarily symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A^{n}$ is a symmetric matrix, should I conclude that A is also symmetric?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965978/does-a-symmetric-matrix-a2-imply-a-symmetric-a).

Comment: Appreciated brothers, its helpful suggestion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Consider the $2 \times 2$ Jordan block $$\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0},$$ or the matrix $$\pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0},$$ which represents an anticlockwise rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I appreciate, its helpful answer.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: More generally, every asymmetric nilpotent matrix is an example, as is every rotation matrix for an angle a rational, nonintegral multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

No you can take the nilpotent matrix 
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0&0 & 1& 0\\
0& 0&0&1\\
0& 0& 0& 0 
\end{array} \right)
$$
M isn't symmetrical but $A^4=0_4$ symmetric

Comment: I appreciate, its helpful answer